# ReadDirectoryChangesW not recognize more than 1 file addition

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to monitor a directory using `ReadDirectoryChangesW`. Whenever a new file is added to the directory I monitor the application should print it's name. The application works fine if I copy one file at a time, but if I try,lets say 2 files at a time, it recognize only one of them.

I'm using this function synchronously.

Here is the code:

The handle to the directory:

```
HANDLE hDir = CreateFile( 
    "d:\\Detect", /* pointer to the file name */
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,                /* access (read-write) mode */
    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_DELETE,  /* share mode */
    NULL, /* security descriptor */
    OPEN_EXISTING, /* how to create */
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, /* file attributes */
    NULL /* file with attributes to copy */
);
```

And `ReadDirectoryChangesW`:

```
ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,&Buffer,sizeof(Buffer),FALSE,
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY|
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION|
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS|
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE|
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE|
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES|
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME|
    FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,&bytesReturned,NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: How big is your buffer?  How are you processing the records written to the buffer?  P.S. You might want to accept some answers.

Comment: This is what will happen when you don't call ReadDirectoryChangesW again after the previous one completes.  A mistake that isn't otherwise visible from your snippet.

Comment: It wasn't ways of me not giving the entire code... I did call ReadDirectoryChangesW again(I invoke this function during an infinite while loop). and the buffer is big enough.

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` to make sure it is succeeding the second time and not reporting an error instead?